# How do I solve a "server version mismatch" with pg_dump when I need BOTH PostgreSQL servers installed?

Tags: postgresql

I installed two PostgreSQL servers in my computer. One is 9.1 and the other is 9.3. I need both servers installed.

When I run pg_dump, however, I get a version mismatch error:

```
server version: 9.3.6; pg_dump version: 9.1.15
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

How can I solve it? (Cannot uninstall either version - I installed the 9.1 first and the 9.3 many months later - I need **both** database servers installed).

Comment: Explicitly run the 9.3 version of `pg_dump`. Both are installed, but only one is the default. See `update-alternatives` for the paths, or `dpkg -L` the postgresql client package to see where they are. Don't have immediate access to an Ubuntu box to show you myself.

Comment: Cannot. The pg_dump command is being run from another application.

Comment: You'll have to change the `PATH` environment variable the app runs with, then.

Comment: I had the same problem. I had to install via the PostgreSQL apt repository: https://askubuntu.com/a/831293/448857

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**TL;DR**: if both PostgreSQL instances are managed by the Ubuntu packages (as they should), just use the `--cluster` option to select the PostgreSQL instance to backup, and it will automatically choose the corresponding version of pg_dump:

`pg_dump --cluster 9.1/main [other pg_dump options]`

or

`pg_dump --cluster 9.3/main [other pg_dump options]`.

`main` is just a default value, run `pg_lsclusters` to see your actual names in the `Cluster` column.

How it works: as installed by the Ubuntu packages, `/usr/bin/pg_dump` is actually a soft-link to `/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper`, whose purpose is precisely to select the correct instance and run the corresponding binary. `--cluster` does not exist in the stock PostgreSQL commands, it's a Debian/Ubuntu addition that is meant to address this multiple versions/multiple paths problem.

This is the same for `psql`, `createdb`, `createuser`, etc. about 18 postgres commands in `/usr/bin` are actually managed by `pg_wrapper`.

See [man pg_wrapper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html) for more.

Comment: what is the version/main for? what is main?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: `version`=major version of postgresql and `main`=default name of the cluster. See the manpages of pg_lsclusters and pg_wrapper.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
sudo find / -name pg_dump
```

to find your versions of `pg_dump` in my case: `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_dump`

so next we can do:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump
```

in order to update to the one we need

Answer (score 3):

If you're running docker, you can run any version of pg_dump without having to manage multiple installations.  This will write a file to `/path/to/dump/to/myfilename.dump` using postgres 12.5:

```
docker run --rm --network=host -v "/path/to/dump/to:/tmp/dump" \
  postgres:12.5 pg_dump -Fc -v --dbname="my_db_bame" -f "/tmp/dump/myfilename.dump"
```

- `--rm` removes the container when the command is done
- `--network=host` connects the container to the host local network
- `-v ...` mounts your host directory (`/path/to/dump/to`) to a temp directory inside the container

You just have to make sure that the directory you mount to (`/tmp/dump`) is the same as the directory that pg_dump is writing to.

Then you can change 12.5 to whatever version you want.

Comment: Nice! This is quick and flexible.