# How do I install PostgreSQL 9.6 on any Ubuntu version?

Tags: apt, software-installation, postgresql

How do I install PostgreSQL 9.6 on any Ubuntu version since it doesn't come by default with the most recent version?

Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) comes with PostgreSQL 9.5 from the [default repositories.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postgresql)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

For the following Ubuntu versions, you can install with the given commands, as per the official [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

## Ubuntu 17.04 - 17.10

Version 9.6 comes with the distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

## Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -sc)-pgdg main"
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

Comment: After install, check `service postgresql status`, and restart if necessary.

Comment: See answer from @Anvesh, you must use `https`

Comment: pgdg doesn't work for arm64

Comment: Note: you will need to use apt-archive now for a lot of the 16.04 and earlier release packages, for example: `deb http://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`

Answer (score 22):

Follow below steps:

**[Reference is taken from this blog.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2017/01/postgresql-how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/)**

**You need to add the latest PostgreSQL repository for the latest version.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
```

**Update and Install PostgreSQL 9.6:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

**Default postgres super user and postgres database is created. You need to set a password for the postgres super user.**

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo passwd postgres
Enter new UNIX password:****
Retype new UNIX password:****
passwd: password updated successfully
```

**If service is not started, you can start the PostgreSQL service.**

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

**Connect PostgreSQL server using postgres user:**

```
ubuntu@:~$ su postgres
Password:****
```

**Create a sample database:**

```
createdb database_name
```

**Connect to that database:**

```
psql -d database_name
```

Comment: What is the password for the postgres user?  you just wrote ****

Comment: @light24bulbs The password is the same as we set with `sudo passwd postgres`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer wouldn't work for me on WSL Ubuntu 18.04.

What did work for me was based on https://medium.com/@philip.mutua/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-14-04-lts-5d463da49ea5

essentially:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6
```

I simply added `-9.6` to the installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/delameko/bd3aa2a54a15c50c723f0eef8f583a44) - 
I am running ubuntu xenial inside vagrant and wanted to upgrade existing postresql official repository vesion 9.5 to 9.6 so that I can use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension which is served best by version 9.6 (officially mentioned in their site)
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please add the steps in case that link goes dead