# Unable to install postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04, postgresql, perl

To install postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 15.04, I have followed steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/831293/517526) and [here](http://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts/)

I am getting this error while installing.

```
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-contrib_9.6+180.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-contrib (9.6+180.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-9.6 (9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Can't locate PgCommon.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PgCommon 
module) (@INC contains: /usr/share/postgresql-common 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.6 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.6:
postgresql-contrib-9.6 depends on postgresql-9.6 (= 9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1); however:
Package postgresql-9.6 is not configured yet.
```

It is saying that Can't locate PgCommon.pm. I am not much familiar with perl modules. So I tried following to install PgCommon but not success.

```
cpan
cpan >> install PgCommon
```

Please help me get it installed. Thanks

Output of `sudo apt-cache madison postgresql | grep -vi sources`

```
postgresql | 9.6+180.pgdg16.04+1 | http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
postgresql | 9.4+166bzr2 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Run `apt-cache madison postgresql | grep -vi sources`, add the output to your question, let me know about the output ;) another thing: Do you have to install **9.6**?

Comment: @Ravexina I have edited question. please check. And yes, I have to install postgres 9.6 because some one have already started project with 9.6 and i have to  configure on my local.

Comment: Are you sure you are running Xenial? it's seems you are on vivid!

Comment: Ohh. Sorry. I am on vivid.

Comment: If you have look at here: `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/` you will find out that `vivid` support  does not provided by `postgresql`, neither with Ubuntu itself. upgrade ;)

Comment: then how do i install on vivid system ?

Comment: I don't know, It's an outdated version which it's support has been ended at February 4, 2016. as I said you should upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem on my machine. This error was blocking installation :

```
Can't locate PgCommon.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PgCommon 
module) (@INC contains: /usr/share/postgresql-common 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1 .)
```

I found out that due to perl dependencies it was failing to install. So I did run following command.

```
which perl
>>>> /usr/local/lib/perl
```

After some googling I found out that actual path should be `/usr/bin/perl` for successfull postgres installation. Perl was installed more than one time on my system. That was the problem. So I deleted directory :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/perl
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/perl
```

After that I run following command to install postgres successfully.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | 
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

Answer (score 2):

here are the easy terminal commands to install postgresql
try this instead

```
     $ sudo apt-get update
     $ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Answer (score 1):

have been stuck on 
postgresql-client-9.6 : Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.6.10) but 9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04 is to be installed for several days.

Tried several solutions like the ones above, but always ended up with the error above.
Finally solved it by

```
sudo aptitude install libpq5=11.0-1.pgdg16.04+2
sudo apt install -f postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6
```